GridControl -Can't openGrid Designer from Run Designer doesn't work In VS2022
Recently we moved to VS2022, we are developing an application using DevExpress 15.2.4 .
The Run Designer feature/button (as seen in screenshot below) isn't available .
Although its works greats with Visual Studio 2017 .
I already search and found that running the DXDesignKeys.exe under components should solve the issue but it doesn't works for me.
I contacted the support team of DevExpress, they mentions the non comptability of Vs2022 and devExpress 15.2.4.
I installed the DevExpress 22.2 and did the same thing under : C:\Program Files\DevExpress 22.2\Components\Tools\Components => no result
I found a thread similar to my issue under the link :https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t751867/gridcontrol-run-designer-doesn-t-work
I installed Universal Windows Platform Development and .NET Core Cross-platform Development with VS2022 => same thing the run design button is missing.

Have you please an idea ?


@lancew have you please an idea on this issue?

What is the .NET version you are targeting? https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/8092/prerequisites?utm_source=SupportCenter&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=docs-feedback&utm_content=T1176079#ide. .NET 8 is not supported by DevExpress 22.2.

We are using .Net 4.0
